# IIS 7 URL Rewrite - match a path and redirect to another in the same domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Let us say that I would like to automatically rewrite

```
http://anysite.com/oldlogin
```

to

```
http://anysite.com/newlogin
```

How should I configure the RewriteRules.config?
I tried

```
  <rule name="Redirect to new login" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://anysite.com/oldlogin" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/newlogin" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

To no avail.

Comment: Classic mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: Thank you. If you present this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You can write your own and accept it.

Comment: You are the one who imparted this knowledge to me, points are meant to reflect that; I insist that you receive them.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<rule name="Redirect to new login" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="oldlogin"/>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://anysite.com/newlogin" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

"oldlogin" could be any path like "profile/login" etc